# OverAir 2.4G/5.8G SMD Antenna OA-W01

Tags: antenna, surface-mount, esp32

has anyone ever used this type of antenna? the brand and type that I'm looking are OverAir SMD Antenna OA-W01, but there is no datasheet and clear way of placement on
PCB. I have attached some pictures that I have found on AliExpress and another site. looking for your recommendations.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No datasheet = no sale!

Answer (score 2):

Yes I have used chip antennas, but no, I have never used an obscure brand like this sold on AliExpress without a good technical datasheet.

This chip antenna is small compared to the wavelengths used, which makes it very sensitive to placement and the adjacent ground plane size and configuration. It will also require a matching network. Unless you have a network analyzer, antenna test chamber, and hours of spare time, you should choose one from a recognized supplier that provides a datasheet and application notes. Most only cost a couple of dollars.